# Getting a null value for in PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, rest, null, thymeleaf

I m having a problems to map the value from thymleaf form to pathvariable in my Controller within **Spring**.

The form from the index file:

```
      <!--/*@thymesVar id="fiatCurrency" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
            <form 
              th:action="@{'/values/' + ${fiatCurrency}}"  method="post"  >
              <select name="fiatCurrency" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option   th:value="USD" th:text="USD"> </option>
                    <option  th:value="EUR" th:text="EUR"> </option>
                    <option   th:value="CNY" th:text="CNY"> </option>
              </select>
            </form>
```

The **controller** looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class DataController {

  private  ApiService apiService;

public DataController(ApiService apiService) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/values","/values/","", "/", "/index","/cryptos"} )
public String index(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("cryptos",apiService.getCrypto(100));

    return "index";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/values/{fiatCurrency}")
public String choseCurrency(Model model,@PathVariable String fiatCurrency){

    model.addAttribute("cryptos",apiService.getInDifferentValues(fiatCurrency));


    return "index";
}
}
```

My problem is it always returns the null value and I'm struggling how to bind inside the `PathVariable` `fiatCurrency` the values **CNY**, **EUR** or **USD** form the `index.html` form.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, you are trying to dynamically change your form action attribute, after the page was rendered. This can't be done using Thymeleaf, at least, the way you are trying to. Remember that Thymeleaf works at server side. So, you have two options to accomplish this.

- Instead of using a path variable, use a parameter instead.
- Dynamically changing the form's action using js.

The easiest would of course be the first option. So, you would need to change post mapping in your controller and change the path variable for a parameter.

Change your controller method for the following.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/values/fiatCurrency")
public String choseCurrency(Model model,
                            @RequestParam("fiatCurrency") String fiatCurrency) {
    model.addAttribute("cryptos", apiService.getInDifferentValues(fiatCurrency));
    return "index";
}
```

And your html would end looking like this.

```
<form id="fiatForm" th:action="@{/values/fiatCurrency}"  method="post">
   <select id="fiatSelect" name="fiatCurrency">
       <option th:value="USD" th:text="USD"> </option>
       <option th:value="EUR" th:text="EUR"> </option>
       <option th:value="CNY" th:text="CNY"> </option>
   </select>
</form>
```

If you don't want to add a button to submit your form, then adding this `jQuery` function will do the trick.

```
$("#fiatSelect").on("change", function() {
   $("#fiatForm").submit();
})
```

I have tried this code and it is already working. Hope it helps.

Comment: it is a help but I m getting an error :         Failed to handle request [POST http://localhost:8080/values/fiatCurrency]: Response status 400 with reason "Required String parameter 'fiatCurrency' is not present"

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my case was that i changed the PathVaribale to RequestBody and it work.
I tried as well to change it to RequestParam  @alain-cruz but it gave me the error from above that i mentioned.

It did btw had to cut off a bit of the variable that i was getting cause i got that it is`@RequestBody String="fiatCurrency=EUR` so i had to get rid off fiatCurrency=.

Cheers